# SQL nvarchar to C# CLR

Tags: c#, sql, string, clr, .net-assembly

I have a stored procedure in SQL which passes the name of the database and servername to a assembly written in C#.  The method called in c# assembly is as follows

```
Private static void GetData(string dbname, string servername)
{
   ---blah
   ---blah
   ---blah
}
```

The problem I am having is when the SQL Instance name or the database name has a backslash (eg. `machinename\2008r2`).

I get exception running the stored procedure unrecognized character `\`.  I tried basic things like replacing `\` with `\\` in the stored procedure before calling the assembly and this fails too.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Issues with \ being interpreted as an escape character only tend to arise with string *literals*, or if you're passing the string to some other system (e.g. `Regex`) that also uses \ as an escape character. If the value's arriving in your code via a `string` parameter, there shouldn't be an issue. There's not enough code in your question to see the issue - all you've shown us is a signature.

Comment: It fails after calling the method hence only the method definition. The very first line inside the method is
throw new exception("In GetData()");
This is to prove that the control has gone into the method. However the exception is never raised.

Comment: Then, I'd hope it's obvious to mention, the error is in code you've *not* shown us. Given that this is apparently a private method, some other code is invoking it - is the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

It's an escape character. You need to use two backslashes.

(eg)

```
 {MachineName\\\NamedInstance}
```

Comment: Yup thats correct. In my stored procedure I tried replacing \ with \\ for both instance name and dbname. I still hit the same issue.  It is do with how sql is passing strings to clr assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you parameterize before passing strings to stored procedures. Don't know what you have set up as your data access code but, for example, the SqlCommand class contains a Parameters collection:

```
 SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand("StoredProc", connection);
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
 command.Parameters["@name"].Value = dbName;
 command.Parameters.Add("@server", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
 command.Parameters["@server"].Value = server;
```